# Pilcrow is added in OkHttp android logcat for long response body

Tags: android-logcat, okhttp, android-studio-2.2

I added `HttpLoggingInterceptor` with log level `BODY`.
My response body is quite long (84.37 KB with measurement tool).
This response takes 22 log lines in Android Studio.

The issue is simple - when I copy it from logcat (pressing ALT and copy only log text) and paste into any online JSON parser, it gives me an error.
While investigating this I found that between lines there is pilcrow (paragraph sign), which is possible to replace in MS Word only (Notepad++ doesn't see it).

When response was approximately 3 times shorter, I didn't face such problem.
**Is it possible to avoid adding pilcrow in output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that those "pilcrows" are just new lines added by Android Studio to reduce max lines length. If so you can replace them with Notepad ++ if you enable "Extended" in the "Search mode" (bottom left radio buttons) on Replace dialog and put "\r\n" as "find what" and an empty string as "replace with".

Also in Notepad ++ you can check View > Show Symbols and enable "Show All Characters" to see what those "pilcrows" are to Notepad ++ (and I suspect they would be `CR` + `LF`).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I tried to do that. Unfortunately, no characters are shown in that place. If I search \r or \n - nothing found. The only way is to copy all in MS Word and replace special - paragraph sign. But it annoys me to do that every time.

Comment: Moreover - I tried all possible options to find paragraph sign in Notepad++ - alt+0244, alt+20 and so on - again nothing found.

Comment: This counds strange. Could you upload a file with an example of your log or just excerpt around those mysterious pilcrow chars somewhere (dropbox?) and provide a link so others can look into the raw data?

Comment: Arghhh, u'r right! I missed "Extended" in search from your answer. Yes, AS inserts CRLF in lines break.

Comment: But the reason it worked earlier, is that if line break is inserted into string value - all is ok. It failed, cause CRLF was inserted inside long digit.